# Downcast from UITabBarItem? to UITabBarItem only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!' Error

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, swift2, xcode7

My code was working well in `Xcode6`. But, after updating to `Xcode7` I got nearly 20 errors and 50 warnings.This might be some syntax change in Swift 2

Solved all those but can't figure out this one : Downcast from `UITabBarItem`? to `UITabBarItem` only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'
The below is the actual code:

```
let tabItems = tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem]  // Error in  this line
for (index, value) in enumerate(tabItems)
{
    var imageName = imageNames[index]
    value.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    value.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, 0, -5.0, 0)
}
```

It shows me 1 error

When I tried doing this:

```
if let tabItems = tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]? {
for (index, value) in tabItems.enumerate()
{
    var imageName = imageNames[index]
    value.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    value.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, 0, -5.0, 0)
}
}
```

It is showing me 5 Errors::

> 1. "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from: -[PFFile _mimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o) 2. "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from: -[PFFile _mimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o) 3. "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from: -[PFFile _mimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o) 4."_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from: -[PFFile _mimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 5.clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just `if let tabItems = tabBar.items {`?

Comment: I don't think the 5 errors are related to your code.  Do you link with the MobileCoreServices library?  (If not, does adding it fix those errors?)

Comment: It shows me 5 errors! Same as mentioned above.                                         1. "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from: -[PFFile _mimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o) 2. "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from: -[PFFile _mimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o) 3. "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from: -[PFFile _mimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o) 4."_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from: -[PFFile _mimeType] in Parse(PFFile.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 5.clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: No. I have not added MobileCoreServices library. But, I don't know why everything is different here. When I click on my project name(Left Pane), I can just see Info and Build Settings That's it. I don't understand where these General, Capabilities, Resource Tags, Build Phases, Build Rules and all went . Anyone know what's wrong here? Thanks

Comment: The missing tabs means you're looking at the project settings instead of the target settings.  (Switch to target in the middle pane.)

Comment: Thanks Phillip :) It worked! I was searching for Build Phases in Target settings!

Answer (score 0):

If there are some TabBarItems, tabBar.items will return you an array of UITabBarItem. If not it will return you nil (It is an optional ).
So it would be "dumb" to cast it again to [UITabBarItem]. this is like saying: I have many apples, make some apples out of it. BUT you need to handle the case that tabBar.items is nil. So you just need to unwrap tabBar.items by adding an "!" to it like this:

```
 let tabItems = tabBar.items!
```

This should work :)

Comment: NO :( . Now, It shows two errors:: 1.'enumerate' is unavailable: all the enumerate() method on the sequence and 2. Cannot invoke 'enumerate' with an argument list of type '(UITabBarItem)'

Comment: for (index, value) in enumerate(tabItems)

Comment: You have to use the for .. in loop from your second piece of code because the global function enumerate was replaced in Swift 2.

Comment: One error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[UITabBarItem]' in let tabItems = tabBar.items!  line

Comment: I am not sure but try to simply delete the "!". So tabItems is an Optional